# Session bus initialization

Tags: python, linux, dbus

I'm trying to use D-Bus to control another application. When using Python bindings, it is possible to use D-Bus just with `dbus.SessionBus()`.

However, other application require to first set up the environment variables `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID`, otherwise they report that the name "was not provided by any .service files".

My question is, why is it necessary for some application to set up the environment variables? Is the a standard procedure to initialize the session bus in some situations?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: python client might be able to use X11 to discover session bus address (in addition to using DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS environment variable). It is stored in `_DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` property of `_DBUS_SESSION_BUS_SELECTION_[hostname]_[uuid]` selection owner window (uuid is content of /var/lib/dbus/machine-id )